# Parsing a text with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I need to parse a text and split it very precisly. I chose to use the regular expressions to do the job but I encounter a problem with an advanced manipulation of it in C#. I would appreciate any help to find the perfect solution, even if I need to take something else than regexes.

**Here are my criteria :**

- The text need to be splited when there is a : ; ! ? \r
- We can also split it if there are dots "." followed by a white-space
- If there are white-spaces behind a separator, they need to be added.
- If there is an URL we do not split the ":"
- If there suspension dots "...", they need to be added behind

**And here is a sample text to understand better :**

*---Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris euismod  : tristiquetellus non egestas; Pellentesque fermentum lectus orci ! A dictum nunc placerat sed ? Quisque eget felis in lacus \rcursus posuere\r\r Aliquam venenatis\r
nisi vitae dictum pharetra.     ---Vivamus semper dolor quam, pellent.esque hendrerit sapien blandit ut.  \r\r\r\rCras sem massa, tempor sit amet nunc id, condimentum facilisis augue...  \rhttps://www.google.com dictum nunc placerat sed*

**And finally the result wanted :**

```
 ---Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
 Mauris euismod  : 
 tristiquetellus non egestas; 
 Pellentesque fermentum lectus orci ! 
 A dictum nunc placerat sed ? 
 Quisque eget felis in lacus \r
 cursus posuere\r\r 
 Aliquam venenatis\r
 nisi vitae dictum pharetra.     \r
 ---Vivamus semper dolor quam, pellent.esque hendrerit sapien blandit ut.  \r\r\r\r
 Cras sem massa, tempor sit amet nunc id, condimentum facilisis augue...  \r
 https://www.google.com dictum nunc placerat sed
```

**I am really far away of the result that is why I am posting here. I try at this moment to success the 1) step. Here is my actual code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Regex r = new Regex(@"(\S*\w+\s*\p{P}*)+[:;!?]+\s*");

            string lorem = "---Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. " +
                "Mauris euismod : " +
                "tristiquetellus non egestas; " +
                "Pellentesque fermentum lectus orci ! " +
                "A dictum nunc placerat sed ? " +
                "Quisque eget felis in lacus \r" +
                "cursus posuere\r\r " +
                "Aliquam venenatis\r " +
                "nisi vitae dictum pharetra. " +
                "---Vivamus semper dolor quam, pellent.esque hendrerit sapien blandit ut. \r\r\r\r" +
                "Cras sem massa, tempor sit amet nunc id, condimentum facilisis augue... \r" +
                "https://www.google.com dictum nunc placerat sed";

            MatchCollection m2 = r.Matches(lorem);

            foreach (Match match in m2)
            {
                string txt = match.Value;
                Console.WriteLine("*{0}*", txt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for reading this and trying to help me. This is kinda urgent and I can not figure out the good combination with the Matches() method from the regexes. Do not hesitate to ask me for more details if necessary.

Comment: all you need is [string.split()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: The thing is that I need to get the white-spaces behind the split character and I did not find out how to get it. That is why I tried to  use the Matches() method with the regex. I really want to use the fewest way to do it properly.

After, if it is not possible, i will parse many times the text with the Split() method but I really want to use something more optimal.

Comment: The URL clause is the problem here. about:config is URL, and also stackoverflow.com is short URL for with implied protocol. How to deal with these two cases?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Actually, I just wanted to check if there are "//" behind the ":" If not, they are not considered as an URL for me but just a simple text. So only `http://stackoverflow.com` would not be splited.

Comment: you could do this `var outputarray = lorem.Split(new string[] { "\r", ". ", "? ", ": ", "! " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` but it will remove the separators ...

Comment: Jerry : Hi Jerry. They will appear to me as a CRLF but the character is just \r. The output is not a problem.

@WiiMaxx : Yes, i already tried this. I successed to keep the separators when i split but the problem was to keep the white-spaces AFTER the separator too.

Comment: Okay, I made [this](http://ideone.com/iKMQiI) for literal `\r` and [this](http://ideone.com/LCNzfZ) for CRLF. Let me know if that's what you want and I'll put it as answer.

Comment: @Jerry : Thank you very much for your answer Jerry. Your first result is really close of what I need. There are just 2 problems on it : *you do not match the space at the end when you split with the ":;!?" * and you do not split with the "\r"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you still haven't been really clear about whether `\r` is supposed to be a carriage return or a literal `\r`, I'll put both:

Literal:

```
(.+?)((?:\.{3} |[:;!?](?!/)|\. )(?:\\r)*\s*|(?:\\r)+\s*|$)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/iKMQiI).

Carriage return:

```
(.+?)((?:\.{3} |[:;!?](?!/)|\. )(?:\r)*\s*|(?:\r)+\s*|$)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/LCNzfZ).

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the Regex, just split the string using the Regex instance like this:
...
string[] splitStringValues = r.split(lorem);
or

char u = ':'; //just initializing

```
        switch (u) 
        {
            case ':':
                //do split work here
                break;
            default:
                //do split work here
                break;
        }
```

Comment: I already tried this but i can not get the white-spaces after the separator when i do this. I find them at the beginning of the next indexes and not at the end after the splited ones. In more, my regex is wrong for the matching.

Comment: my initial thought was for you to have used a switch case, I just edited my answer, why don't you try it out.

Comment: Unfortunally, the problem is not to split the text but to get the right pattern abled to handle all the cases said on top for the split. Your solution involves many traitments in the switch case. I want to avoid this by using a Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out  `(((http(s*))\://){1}\S+)|((\S*\w+\s*\p{P}*)+[:;!?]+\s*)|(\...)`

Comment: Unfortunaly, my pattern does not work properly, so yours neither. I am matching nothing.

Comment: Hard to say if this works, because it's been over a minute and it still hasn't returned. I think you have a very inefficient regex there.